# How to group database column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, qsqlquery

I need to get a sales Ref. wise report which have several filters. I tried this query to generate the report.

```
SELECT
    sp.SlpCode,
    sp.SlpName,
    sp.Telephone,
    COUNT(od.DocNum) count,
    ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(od.U_ArtWork) WHERE od.U_ArtWork = 'NotRec'), 0) Artwork,
    ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(od.U_DetailPending) WHERE od.U_DetailPending = 'No'), 0) DetailPrinting
FROM 
    OSLP sp
LEFT JOIN 
    ORDR od ON SP.SlpCode = od.SlpCode
WHERE
    sp.Telephone IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
    sp.SlpCode, sp.SlpName, sp.Telephone,
    od.U_ArtWork, od.U_DetailPending
ORDER BY
    sp.SlpName ASC;
```

The results are like this:

[image]

But I need those results like this:

[image]

Comment: I think SlpName has different values. 'Mark' will not group by ' Mark'. Try to remove  sp.SlpName, sp.Telephone, od.U_ArtWork columns from group by and show what results did you get.

Answer (score 3):

Remove `od.U_ArtWork,od.U_DetailPending` from `group by` - you are using these columns in aggregation so no need to add in group by clause

```
SELECT
    sp.SlpCode,
    sp.SlpName,
    sp.Telephone,
    COUNT(od.DocNum) count,
    COUNT(case when od.U_ArtWork = 'NotRec' then od.U_ArtWork end) Artwork,
    COUNT(case when od.U_DetailPending='No' then od.U_DetailPending end) DetailPrinting
FROM OSLP sp
LEFT JOIN ORDR od
    ON SP.SlpCode = od.SlpCode
WHERE
    sp.Telephone IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
    sp.SlpCode,
    sp.SlpName,
    sp.Telephone
ORDER BY
    sp.SlpName ASC
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, why is that?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, thank u :) I didn't notice that he didn't use case when

Answer (score 3):

You may try aggregating only on the three columns `SlpCode`, `SlpName`, and `Telephone`:

```
SELECT
    sp.SlpCode,
    sp.SlpName,
    sp.Telephone,
    COUNT(od.DocNum) count,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN od.U_ArtWork = 'NotRec' THEN 1 END) AS Artwork,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN od.U_DetailPending = 'No' THEN 1 END) AS DetailPrinting
FROM OSLP sp
LEFT JOIN ORDR od
    ON SP.SlpCode = od.SlpCode
WHERE
    sp.Telephone IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
    sp.SlpCode,
    sp.SlpName,
    sp.Telephone,
ORDER BY
    sp.SlpName;
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, "poached" this is not a right word Tim, there was a wrong and you suggest me to make it correct, A person like u who has more reputation does not seem good to think like this

Comment: I like my eggs scrambled, not poached :-(

Comment: whatever you like - that does not matter. But here, there are lots to learn _ i never have any intention to copy other's answer and I never do it. And from you guys we learn so you should have broad mentality @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen I wrote this query to create a report using crystal reports.I need to filter that report using od.DocDate.How can I do this? If I add od.DocDate to query  it is occurred the same error which I mentioned before.